# Undifined values while converting little endian 32bits into integer

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to convert values from a buffer that i receive from web server. I am parsing the buffer into  hex strings to get the bytes intended so i can convert it to integers from 32bits and 16bits.

The result intended from the function below should be, 09 00 00 00 = 9, but i am getting 00undefinedundefined09 and 00undefined00undefined or empty string when console logging the string 's' .

'numb' is the string buffer already sliced '09 00 00 00'

```
function translateLittleEndian32bits(numb){
    var arrtemp = [];
    var s = "";
    var q = 0;
    console.log('numb: ' + numb);
    for(var i = 0; i < 8; i ++ ){
        var numb1 = numb.charAt(i);
        var numb2 = numb.charAt(i+1);
        var numbF = numb1 + numb2; 
        arrtemp[q]= numbF;
        console.log("arrtemp >> : " + arrtemp[q]);
        q++;
        i++;
    }
    s = ((arrtemp[3]) + (arrtemp[2])+(arrtemp[1])+(arrtemp[0]));
    console.log('s >>>> ' + s);
    var int32LE = parseInt(s, 16); 
    return int32LE;
}

function translateLittleEndian16bits(numb){
    var arrtemp = [];
    var s = "";
    var q = 0;
    console.log('numb: ' + numb);
    for(var i = 0; i < 4; i ++ ){
        var numb1 = numb.charAt(i);
        var numb2 = numb.charAt(i+1);
        var numbF = numb1 + numb2; 
        arrtemp[q]= numbF;
        console.log("arrtemp >> : " + arrtemp[q]);
        q++;
        i++;
    }
    s = ((arrtemp[1])+(arrtemp[0]));
    console.log('s >>>> ' + s);
    var int16LE = parseInt(s, 16); 
    return int16LE;
}
```

**Updated**

Here i receive the code and slice so i can have the intended parts of the buffer that i need to work with:

```
for(var i = 0; i < valuesKey.length; i++){
        var tempType1 = valuesKey[i+6];
        var tempType2 = valuesKey[i+7];
        var tempType = tempType1 + tempType2;
        switch(tempType){
            case '69':                                                                  //integer (int32_t) done
                valueTypeKey = valuesKey.slice(i, i+16);
                var valueTypeKeysT = valueTypeKey.toString('hex');
                var valueTypeKeysF = valueTypeKeysT.replaceAll(",", "");
                var key = valueTypeKeysF.slice(i, i+6);
                var type = valueTypeKeysF.slice(i+6, i+8);
                var val = valueTypeKeysF.slice(i+8, i+16);
                var valueInt32 = translateLittleEndian32bits(val);
                //arrayValueType[q] = key + type + valueInt32;
                //arrayValueType[q] = valueTypeKeysF;
                i += 15;
                q++;
                break;
```

Comment: "*I am parsing the buffer into hex strings to get the bytes*" - uh, **don't**? When you have a raw buffer already, you can directly access the bytes! What exactly are you receiving from the server? Please show that part of the code as well. Then use a [`DataView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView)!

Comment: Updated, hope this make sense to you

Comment: `Buffer.from(numb.replace(/\s/g, ''), 'hex').readInt32LE()`

Comment: @robertklep, can you explain? thank you for the tip, but that doesn't help me understanding the concept

Comment: @Tiago it's (mostly) explained in the [`Buffer` documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html).

Comment: @Tiago `.toString('hex')` is where you went wrong. What exactly is `valuesKey` to begin with? Where does it come from?